# Group items by content of list

Tags: c#

Lets say i got a something like this:

```
public class Subscriber{
    public string Name {get; set;}  
}

public class SomeData{
    public string Content {get; set;}   
}

public class InputData {
    public Subscriber Subscribers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SomeData> DataItems { get; set; }
}

public class QueueItem {
    public IEnumerable<Subscriber> Subscribers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SomeData> DataItems { get; set; }
}
```

Now lets say i get a `List<InputData>` full of "Subscribers" with a list of data for each subscriber.

Now i want to compare the list of data of each subscriber, and end up with a `List<QueueItem>`, where if 2 subscribers have the same set of data items, they would be 1 `QueueItem`.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: It seems you need to define an IEqualityComparer for list<somedata>, then do the normal groupby

Comment: Can you make an example?

Comment: IMO, using a `List` as a key to a `Dictionary` seems like a terrible design decision.  I suggest rethinking how you are organizing data.  If possible/needed, use a second dictionary to help the logic.

Comment: I suggest you encapsulate your subscriber/item pairs in a class and create accessor methods for all the information you need, like `GetItemsForSubscriber()` or `GetSubscribersForItem()`.

Comment: well yeah, its really just to simplify my question. i would end up in a model, can just try and update my question to reflect that

Comment: Just updated question, maybe this makes a bit more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique is using EqualityComparer with Enumerable.SequenceEqual()

```
public class Subscriber
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // For compare
    public override bool Equals(object obj) { return string.Equals(this.Name, ((Subscriber)obj).Name); }
    public override int GetHashCode() { return this.Name.GetHashCode(); } 
}

public class SomeData
{
    public string Content { get; set; }

    // For compare
    public override bool Equals(object obj) { return string.Equals(this.Content, ((SomeData)obj).Content); }
    public override int GetHashCode() { return this.Content.GetHashCode(); } 
}

public class InputData
{
    public Subscriber Subscribers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SomeData> DataItems { get; set; }

    // Should always initialize an empty collection
    public InputData() { this.DataItems = new List<SomeData>(); }
}

public class QueueItem
{
    public IEnumerable<Subscriber> Subscribers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SomeData> DataItems { get; set; }

    // Should always initialize an empty collection
    public QueueItem() { this.Subscribers = new List<Subscriber>(); this.DataItems = new List<SomeData>(); }
}

public class DataItemsEqualityComparer : EqualityComparer<IEnumerable<SomeData>>
{

    public override bool Equals(IEnumerable<SomeData> x, IEnumerable<SomeData> y)
    {
        return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x.OrderBy(i => i.Content), y.OrderBy(i => i.Content));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<SomeData> obj)
    {
        return obj.Select(i => i.GetHashCode()).Sum().GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var data = new List<InputData>();
var fruits = new[] { new SomeData() { Content = "apple" }, new SomeData() { Content = "pear"} };
var colors = new[] { new SomeData() { Content = "red" }, new SomeData() { Content = "blue" }, new SomeData() { Content = "green" } };

data.Add(new InputData() { Subscribers = new Subscriber() { Name = "Alice" }, DataItems = new List<SomeData>(fruits) });
data.Add(new InputData() { Subscribers = new Subscriber() { Name = "Bob" }, DataItems = new List<SomeData>(colors) });
data.Add(new InputData() { Subscribers = new Subscriber() { Name = "Charlie" }, DataItems = new List<SomeData>(fruits) });

List<QueueItem> groupedData = data.GroupBy(
    i => i.DataItems, 
    i => i.Subscribers, 
    new DataItemsEqualityComparer())
    .Select(i => new QueueItem() { Subscribers = i, DataItems = i.Key }).ToList();
```

Result

```
QueueItem :
  Subscribers:
  - Alice
  - Charlie
  Data:
  - apple
  - pear
QueueItem :
  Subscribers:
  - Bob
  Data:
  - red
  - blue
  - green
```

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, and got it working with my code, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var queue = Dictionary(Subscriber, List<SomeData>);
//And lets just for example add some data
var items1 = new List<SomeData>();
items1.Add(new SomeData("test"));
items1.Add(new SomeData("test2"));

var items2 = new List<SomeData>();
items2.Add(new SomeData("test"));

queue.Add(new Subscriber("Peter"), items1);
queue.Add(new Subscriber("Luke"), items1);
queue.Add(new Subscriber("Anna"), items2);

Dictionary<Subscriber, List<SomeData>> myDictionary = queue
    .GroupBy(o => o.PropertyName)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Comment: Can you explain how you would use that with my example?

Comment: o.PropertyName is the property for groupoing from "Subscriber" class... i guess the property name is "Name"

Comment: i want to end out with Dictionary<List<Subscriber>, List<SomeData>>();, and you define it as Dictionary<Subscriber, List<SomeData>>(); from start..